# Chart.js How to hide specyfic labels but keep data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

I have years on x-axis, and it's an array like this `labels = [2020, 2021, 2030, 2035, 2038, 2040, 2050, 2060]`, on y-axis I have this data `data = [0, 20, 25, 50, 22, 78, 75, 10, 105]` but I'm replacing every year that can't be divided by 10 with empty string.

The problem is that every empty string still has some "width" in labels, it should be hidden, but data should be visible.

```
            <Line
                data={{
                    labels: labels.map(value => value % 10 === 0 ? value : ''),
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label,
                            data,
                            pointRadius: labels.map(value => value % 10 === 0 ? 2 : 0)
                        }
                    ]
                }}
            />
```

I'm trying to achieve this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `labels`, you can try to define a `scales.x.ticks.callback` function within `options`.

```
< Line
  data = {
    {
      labels,
      datasets: [{
        label,
        data,
        pointRadius: labels.map(value => value % 10 === 0 ? 2 : 0)
      }]
    }
  }
  options = {
    {
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            callback: value => value % 10 === 0 ? value : null
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
/>
```

For further information, please take a look at [Creating Custom Tick Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) from the `Chart.js` documentation.

A running example can be found at this [sample](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html) page.

Comment: It does work same as my previous code, I need now somehow hide labels (to not occupy any width) but keep data for that label visible in the chart.